# Launch at the click of a button a universal app

Tags: c#, wpf, win-universal-app, buttonclick

I'm making a software in WPF .
Within the solution I added other projects , one of which is universal app windows .
My question is , I would need to start the project WPF project universal app , wandering through the network did not find much . And ' possible?

In summary , by clicking a button in the project WPF , it must begin with the universal app .

It's possible ? Thank you

Comment: Do you need to launch the app for a specific purpose e.g. to edit a particular file, to retrieve some data, or just show the app?

Comment: I have to run the application that is CameraCapture , serves to make the picture and put it in a specific folder . The code is all written , I just throw it and to enable users to take pictures from the tablet . 
CameraCapture: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CameraCaptureUI-Sample-845a53ac

Answer (score 1):

The way to launch Windows apps is to use Launcher.LaunchUriAsync.

```
// The URI to launch
string uriToLaunch = @"cameracapture:CaptureImage?folder=C%3A%5C%5CMyImages";

// Create a Uri object from a URI string 
var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);

// Launch the URI
async void DefaultLaunch()
{
   // Launch the URI
   var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

   if (success)
   {
      // URI launched
   }
   else
   {
      // URI launch failed
   }
}
```

For this to work you will need a URI scheme for your app. To handle a URI association, specify the corresponding URI scheme name in the app manifest file.
Go to your app’s package.appxmanifest file and navigate to the Declarations tab. You want to add a new declaration of type ‘Protocol’ and you’ll need to specify the name property which will be the actual URI protocol you want your app to handle. e.g. cameracapture.

To handle the incoming parameters override the OnActivated method in the App.xaml.cs code behind:

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
    {
        var eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
        if (eventArgs != null)
        {
            var uri = eventArgs.Uri;
            tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());

            // URI association launch for cameracapture.
            if (tempUri.Contains("cameracapture:CaptureImage?folder="))
            {
                // Get the folder (after "folder=").
                int folderIndex = tempUri.IndexOf("folder=") + 7;
                string folder = tempUri.Substring(folderIndex);

                // Do something with the request
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the error on Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri) return this:  Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).
maybe i have to set something ?

Comment: Or, are you trying to launch the app from a background thread?

Comment: Capabilities is all signed. and the error i always "Access is denied".

string uriToLaunch = @"CameraCapture:CameraCapture";

var uri = new Uri(uriToLaunch);
var success = await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri);

It ' possible that I did not specify well the assembly ? or something like that ?

Comment: Have you set up the app manifest to handle that URI and deployed the app?

Comment: They are obliged to create and deploy the application ?

Comment: Well if there is nothing ready to handle the URI request, then what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I did the distribution package , but the error remains . Thank you anyway for your time .